# Multiple projects on single window in Github Atom editor

Tags: github, editor, atom-editor

Is it able to add multiple projects on same window in Github Atom editor as in sublime text? 
Any options ?

Answer (score 4):

The option to add multiple *project folders* has been added to the Atom editor in April 2015.

See [this blog post](http://blog.atom.io/2015/04/15/multi-folder-projects.html) for more information.

To use this feature, you have the following options:

- Provide multiple folders on the Atom command line: `atom ./folder1 ./folder2`
- Use the `Application: Add Project Folder` command from the command palette.

Comment: Project-manager opens a new window for each project, so it's not a solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer - the feature is now supported by Atom, you can open multiple project folders in the same editor window.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Atom 1.23 and you currently are able to do this.

All you have to do is go to File -> Add Project Folder

[image]

[image]